# android, different code used for landscape and portrait

Tags: android, layout

how to write the code that read the size of the screen. i have 4 different layout, "layout", "layout-land", "layout-large", and "layout-large-land"

every one of the layout i need to write a different code for each of them, for example at the "layout" , i have this code `imagebutton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` , but at the landscape screen, i have remove the imagebutton1. so i plan to if else statement, but i duno how to determine the size of the screen by using android java, need some guide here.

Comment: try looking at Android's [supporting different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: thx for the link, i have go through before i post this, but it din't show me the syntax on how to determine the screen size they use? but i found this `getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)==Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE` but this code cant be use, can anyone give me more accurate answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you could just do something like this:

```
ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.image_button);

if (imageButton1 != null) {
    // if the imagebutton isn't found in the view hierarchy,
    // then don't attempt to manipulate it.
    imagebutton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Otherwise you can use:

```
Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();

boolean isLarge = (conf.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) == 
                      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;

boolean isLandscape = (conf.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

boolean isLargeLand = isLarge && isLandscape;
```